# Writing console output to a file in python

Tags: python, regex, formatting, output

Sorry for this question, I know that this is a recurrent topic, but I'm incapable of solving my problem, which in fact, is simple to describe: I want to write into a file the output of an execution **as it is**. I mean, I have an output like this (sorry for the mess):

```
.251.242.133|:80... connected.\r\nHTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK\r\nLength: 2371567 (2.3M) [application/x-gzip]\r\nSaving to: `110907_ERP000591.tar.gz\'\r\n\r\n\r 0% [                                       ] 0           --.-K/s              \r 0% [                                       ] 23,003       104K/s              \r 3% [>                                      ] 82,863       184K/s              \r 8% [==>                                    ] 192,363      282K/s              \r15% [=====>                                 ] 371,943      411K/s              \r26% [=========>                             ] 634,175      563K/s              \r39% [==============>                        ] 925,283      680K/s              \r52% [===================>                   ] 1,250,295    790K/s              \r63% [=======================>               ] 1,497,035    830K/s              \r73% [===========================>           ] 1,732,663    861K/s              \r81% [==============================>        ] 1,937,063    867K/s              \r88% [=================================>     ] 2,099,123    855K/s              \r95% [====================================>  ] 2,268,483    847K/s              \r100%[======================================>] 2,371,567    849K/s   in 2.7s    \r\n\r\n2012-11-01 15:34:10 (849 KB/s) - `110907_ERP000591.tar.gz\' saved [2371567/2371567]\r\n\r\n110907_ERP000591/\r\n110907_ERP000591/1_110907_ERP000591_2_fastq.txt\r\n110907_ERP000591/1_110907_ERP000591_1_fastq.txt\r\n/home/travis/opt/bcbb/nextgen/tests/data/automated/../100326_FC6107FAAXX\r\n--2012-11-01 15:34:10--  http://chapmanb.s3.amazonaws.com/100326_FC6107FAAXX.tar.gz\r\nResolving chapmanb.s3.amazonaws.com (chapmanb.s3.amazonaws.com)... 205.251.242.133\r\nConnecting to chapmanb.s3.amazonaws.com (chapmanb.s3.amazonaws.com)|205.251.242.133|:80... connected.\r\nHTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK\r\nLength: 7014592 (6.7M) [application/x-gzip]\r\nSaving to: `100326_FC6107FAAXX.tar.gz\'\r\n\r\n\r 0% [                                       ] 0           --.-K/s              \r 0% [                                       ] 17,163      77.9K/s              \r 0% [                                       ] 64,775       147K/s              \r 2% [                                       ] 174,843      263K/s              \r 5% [=>                                     ] 399,683      456K/s              \r12% [===>                                   ] 866,883      790K/s              \r25% [========>                              ] 1,798,363   1.33M/s              \r45% [================>                      ] 3,178,955   1.90M/s              \r65% [========================>              ] 4,592,803   2.41M/s              \r65% [========================>              ] 4,629,303   2.17M/s              \r67% [=========================>             ] 4,761,595   2.02M/s              \r74% [============================>          ] 5,245,423   2.03M/s              \r83% [===============================>       ] 5,862,435   2.08M/s              \r100%[======================================>] 7,014,592   2.46M/s   in 2.7s    \r\n\r\n2012-11-01 15:34:13 (2.46 MB/s) -
```

So, as you can see, I have a weirdly formatted output, which is shown like this in the terminal:

```
/home/travis/opt/bcbb/nextgen/tests/data/automated/../100326_FC6107FAAXX
--2012-11-01 15:34:10--  http://chapmanb.s3.amazonaws.com/100326_FC6107FAAXX.tar.gz
Resolving chapmanb.s3.amazonaws.com (chapmanb.s3.amazonaws.com)... 205.251.242.133
Connecting to chapmanb.s3.amazonaws.com (chapmanb.s3.amazonaws.com)|205.251.242.133|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 7014592 (6.7M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: `100326_FC6107FAAXX.tar.gz'

100%[======================================>] 7,014,592   2.46M/s   in 2.7s    

2012-11-01 15:34:13 (2.46 MB/s) - `100326_FC6107FAAXX.tar.gz' saved [7014592/7014592]
```

Much nicer... I want to write the output to a file with this form, so I cant just strip the \r\n or something like that, because this way will appear one line for each step in the progress of the download. I just want to write a file with the final output.

Any help?

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I should have been clearer: It's not the result of a command but, as commented below, the result of the parsing of a json file. You can reproduce the output:

```
import urllib
import json

string_to_write = json.loads(urllib.urlopen('https://travis-ci.org/jobs/3019024.json').read())['log']
```

Comment: what exactly was the command that led to this output?

Comment: This should basically work as it is. Meaning, if you got a string `s = 'foo\n\rbar'` in Python, and write that out to a file with `open('outfile.txt, 'w').write(s)`, the file should contain those line endings and render correctly when `cat`ed for example.

Comment: Although if you are on Windows, there is a braindead distinction between "binary mode" and "text mode" when writing files. So you might need to use either the `'wb'` or `'w'` mode, not sure. See the comments in the Python [docs about reading and writing files](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: Sorry, in fact it's not a command itself, it's the result of parsing the return of [travis-ci api](www.travis-ci.org), concretely, the field ['matrix'][0]['id'] from the json returned by [this url](https://travis-ci.org/guillermo-carrasco/bcbb/builds/3019023.json)

Comment: This looks like `wget` output, which assumes a TTY. Perhaps you should use the `--progress=dot` switch instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to work:

```
re.sub(r"(?m)^.*\r(?!$)", "", text)
```

The `(?m)` flag indicates that this is a multiline regex, so that `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of each line, rather than the whole text.

So, we match everything `.*` from the start of the line `^` up to and including a carriage return `\r`, unless that carriage return is immediately followed by the end of the line `(?!$)` - as it will be if your text contains CRLF linebreaks. And, replace the match with the empty string.

Comment: I'v got '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n2012-11-01 15:34:13 (2.46 MB/s) ' is it really good result?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're on a *NIX system. If this output is generated by running `progn` (which could really be `python myscript.py`) on the command line, you could just as easily do this:

```
progn > logfile
```

This way, the output of `progn` is saved to `logfile` without stripping any characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just remove what is hidden on terminal then you could try this ->

```
# t is your text
''.join([i for i in t.split('\r') if i.startswith('\n') or i.startswith('100%')])
```

Solution is tricky (!) but I think it could probably works for you.